# locale issue workaround in PostgreSQL data directory upgrade from 8.4 to 9.5

Tags: postgresql, locale, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-8.4

Desciption of the issue is given at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912502/locale-issue-while-upgrading-data-directory-from-postgresql-8-4-to-9-5). It seems that it is a PostgreSQL bug only. To resolve this issue, there seems to be only a single workaround, which is to create a list of locale (map) with key as `<Language>_<Country>.<CodePage>`and value as `<Language>, <Country>`.

For example:

```
English_United States.1252 = English, United States
...
```

Since value of parameter `--locale` is accepted in the format of `<Language>, <Country>`whereas output of command `SHOW LC_COLLATE` is in the format of `<Language>_<Country>.<CodePage>`. So, during an ugrade I will get the value of *lc_collate* cmd and get the corresponding value from the list and provide it during PostgreSQL 9.5 installation.

How do I convert `<Language>_<Country>.<CodePage>` to appropriate format for successful installation ?

Comment: First mistake, it's not "8.x" to "9.x". Each "8.x" and "9.x" is a distinct major version. Yes, that versioning is stupid and we finally fixed it with PostgreSQL 10. But "8.3" to "8.4" is exactly as major an upgrade as "8.4" to "9.0".

Comment: @CraigRinger My mistake. I have updated the post. Any idea about how to convert locale from one format to another, as asked above ?